# aligning map to map_frame origin

Tags: navigation, mapping, gps, rviz, navsat-transform-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am using two `ekf_localization_nodes` and one `navsat_transform_node` from `robot_localization` package. One `ekf_localization_node` is used to fuse wheel encoder and imu data, the other one is used to fuse wheel encoder, imu and GPS data (output from the `navsat_transform_node`). So far this setup has been working more or less fine.

My question is this:

When the robot initialises, it takes the first GPS data received and set that as the origin of the `map_frame` in rviz. Because previously I have just been looking at the trajectories of the GPS data and the `odometry/filtered_map`, there wasn't a need to use a map. However, currently I would like to map this trajectory onto a map to see if the trajectory is correct. Assuming that I already have a .pgm map of the location, how can I map the starting position of the robot (aka the first GPS data) onto this map? I can't fix a starting point on the map itself as well because everytime the first GPS data will be different. Is there a way to automatically map the first GPS data to the correct position on the .pgm map?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276947/aligning-map-to-map_frame-origin/) by [cheng1234567](https://answers.ros.org/users/32800/cheng1234567/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you considered using `mapviz`?

http://wiki.ros.org/mapviz

You can just turn on `publish_filtered_gps` in `navsat_transform_node` and plot it directly, I would think.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2018-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1